# How to keep a memory costly android service always on?

Tags: android, service

I'm writing an android app that can stitch individual images into a panoramic image using openCV. the stitching part works fine. Right now im doing the stitching in a service that runs as a separate process which runs using `startForeground()`(Also the stitching happens as an AsyncTask). the process works fine for four to five images but when it goes beyond that it takes around 300-350MB of memory and the service gets killed because of that. Is there a way to make a service run indefinitely?

Comment: running service indefinitely will not solve your problem. you will have to analyze memory consumption of service in question and optimize it.

Comment: My Service is running perfectly until i call `stopself()` normally. but it is getting killed by android in order to retain memory and since the service calls a native openCV method which performs some costly operations i cant think of optimization.

Comment: you need some cost cutting ;)

Comment: lol! btw i fixed the issue. I resized the high res images to 1/5th of its actual size and the problem solved.although the resultant image is little low quality but thats fine with me.

Comment: That's what I was talking about ;). Good to hear you solved it. Now post your solution as answer so it will help others coming across this question

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found a workaround for the problem. Before stitching images I am scaling down to the factor of 5 and then stitching. Now my app dont consume more than 100 MB and android dont force close my app. Although this will reduce the quality of the resulting image it is fine with me.

thanks!!!